# cursor not follow mouse click in the text input field in Firefox

Tags: firefox, input, slider, focus

I created a simple Jquery slider:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

and attach one text input field to the slider handler by using Javascript:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider();
var value = "<input id='handler1InputValue' type = 'text' spellcheck = 'false'      style='position:absolute;width:70px;height:15px;text-align:center;left:-2px;font-size:10px;display:block;' ></input>";
$( ".ui-slider-handle" ).html(value);
$( ".ui-slider-handle" ).unbind();
$( "#handler1InputValue" ).val(77777);
```

But in Firefox, the cursor does not follow mouse click in the text input field, mouse selection doesn't work as well, while everything works in Chrome side.

Anybody know how to solve the problem in Firefox side? And you can try the test sample here:        [slider with text input field](http://jsfiddle.net/xdliu/FhXVq/)

Comment: This is caused by input being inside the anchor tag. So far I haven't found a good solution to disable this functionality for existing anchor tag, so in my project I will restructure the code to not use a-tag as the input container.